# Vercel deploy serverless function has crashed

Tags: deployment, mern, server-side, vercel

Hi guys i am trying to **deploy my MERN app to vercel**, but i have a problem when i try to deploy the backend i get an error, even though when i tried it on the local server there was no error at all

can you help me to fix this ?

**here is the error : **

```
This Serverless Function has crashed.

Your connection is working correctly.

Vercel is working correctly.

500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
```

**my index.js :**

```
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import UserRoute from "./routes/UserRoute.js"
import ContentRoutes from "./routes/contentRoute.js";
import MessageRouter from "./routes/MessageRoute.js"

import connectDB from "./mongodb/connect.js";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
mongoose.connect

app.use(cors(
  {
    origin: {"https://hotel-backend-xi.vercel.app"},
    methods: {"POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT"},
    credentials: true
  }
));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "25mb" }));
app.use(UserRoute);
app.use(ContentRoutes);
app.use(MessageRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello hotel")
  console.log("Hello hotel")
})

const startServer = () => {
  try {
    connectDB(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
    app.listen(5000, () => {
      console.log("Server listening on 5000 http://localhost:5000");
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

startServer();
```

**here is my dependencies (package.json) :**

> ```
> {
>   "name": "backend",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "",
>   "type": "module",
>   "main": "index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "start": "nodemon index",
>     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
>   },
>   "keywords": [],
>   "author": "",
>   "license": "ISC",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
>     "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
>     "cloudinary": "^1.37.3",
>     "cors": "^2.8.5",
>     "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
>     "express": "^4.18.2",
>     "joi": "^17.9.2",
>     "joi-password-complexity": "^5.1.0",
>     "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
>     "mongoose": "^7.3.1",
>     "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
>     "uuid": "^9.0.0"
>   }
> }
> ```

i have tried several ways, but it doesn't work
i hope you can help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 1):

It has a simple Solution Go to MongoDB in your Project Find Network Access in security tab ,

1. Add IP Address
2. Allow Access From Anywhere
3. Confirm

This Solved My problem.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was making the name of my mongodb uri in my .env the same in the environment variables on vercel thus mine was: MONGODB_URI so I wrote the same thing on vercel there I added my connection string. Find out more on: [why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed](https://vercel.com/guides/why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed)

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to run a web server, not a [serverless function](https://vercel.com/guides/npm-run-start-not-working). You can [run an Express app as a function](https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel), but what you have currently would need to be run on a conventional server, not Vercel.